# Inserting an image into PHP code if custom field = true

Tags: php, image

I have the following code which is pulling in a custom field named phone.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_phone', true ); ?>
```

I additionally however want to add a little icon to the left of it. So I realise I have to include the src link somewhere, have tried the below, but am having no joy. Sorry a bit new...

```
<?php
$value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_phone', true );
if( $value == 'True' ) { echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image.png">'; echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_phone', true ); ?>
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to invert ' and " in the string definition. Which leads to

```
"<img src='/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image.png'>";
```

Comment: did you try to isolate the ...
    echo "<img src='/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image.png'>";
... then to see if it is displayed ?
Also check that the path is right...
I don't see any reason for that behavior

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `/` from `src` then try..

```
echo '<img src="wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image.png">';
```